# Easier way to add on a newline in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code:

```
for (BNRItem *item in self.items) {
    [descriptionString appendString:[item description]];
    [descriptionString appendString:@"\n"];

}
```

Is there a way to do this in one line instead of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `descriptionString` is an `NSMutableString`, use:

```
for (BNRItem *item in self.items) {
    [descriptionString appendFormat:@"%@\n", item];
}
```

No need to call the `description` method explicitly on `item`.

Answer (score 3):

```
[descriptionString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [item description]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Most people use stringWithFormat for everything, but you could do this with stringByAppendingString, e.g. :

```
for (BNRItem *item in self.items) {
    [descriptionString appendString:[[item description]stringByAppendingString:@"\n"]];
 }
```

If I was doing this in a lot of places in the code, I'd put a one line category method on NSString, e. g.

```
@implementation NSString (LineEnding)

- (NSString*)plusNewLine {
  return [self stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
}
@end
```

and then you could write code like :

```
    [descriptionString appendString:item.description.plusNewLine];
```